# Prove that ${F_{n+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$ where ${F_{n}}$ is n-th Fibonacci number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

Question:

**Prove** that ${F_{n+1}}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-k}{k}$ where ${F_{n}}$ is n-th Fibonacci number.

My idea:

I guess I could use induction so ${F_{n}}\to{F_{n+1}}$ where we see that for $n=0$ and $n=1$ it is true so that would be our base. Then - ${F_{n+1}}= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n-k+1}{k}$ but I have no idea what to do with it, does anyone have any idea? Maybe use some binomial or Fibonacci properties?

Comment: Remember $\binom{m}k=\binom{m-1}{k-1}+\binom{m-1}k$.

Comment: How does that help me though? I have two arguments at the top of the binomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}\stackrel{I.H.}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-k-1}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \binom{n-k-2}{k}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-k-1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-k-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k-1}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}.
$$